# Checks not showing in the correct location

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a partial view with a table below.  I am trying to display checkbox in the first column, but none are displaying correctly.

```
<h4>Select Skills...</h4>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ManagePartial", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "PartialDiv", HttpMethod = "Get", OnComplete = "preventpartialUpdate" }))
{
    <p>
        Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
        <input type="submit" name="command" value="Search..."/>
    </p>
}
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Checked</th>
        <th>Heading</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>

                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.CheckedStatus)
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.CheckedStatus)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => item.Skill)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Skill)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The checkboxs are showing up chrome developer tools, but the screen is showing (either one checkbox or all stacked in one location(top left corner). Image attached.

Any Ideas would be appreciated thanks.

[image]

Comment: This must be design issue, can u create fiddle for your html code. Or change some css for it to work...

Comment: Check the css for the checkboxes (note your code is generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which would not bind to a collection on post back and `@Html.HiddenFor(x => item.CheckedStatus)` is a bit pointless - its just ignored)

Comment: Have you tried to disable all CSS on the page, might be just a stylesheet issue.